# Unity3D Game Custom Launcher Patching Advice

Tags: wpf, windows, unity-game-engine, deployment, patch

I have a unity3D game I'm self distributing privately for Windows platforms. I've made a custom launcher for my game, using WPF. It'll handle patching and updates of the game (almost everything apart from a lightweight 'core' containing the scripts, is an asset bundle, and is patchable). The launcher has an installer, like a setup.exe file. Most of the time users will install it on "Program Files\GameName\". The problem being, this is the install location of the launcher itself, and while I'd like to put the game in a sub-directory of this folder, it means I need to give administrator authorisation to the launcher so it can download files to the Program Files dir, which I can't confirm all users WILL be able to do, or will want to do. I COULD just put the game in the apps local data file (Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);), but that would mean it doesn't matter where the user installs the 'app', all the gigs of content will still be forced onto the C drive for local data, which some people with small SSD drives wouldn't like.

Does anyone have any suggestions about how to get around this deployment hurdle?

Currently I CAN save the asset bundles to the sub-directory from a server without an issue, but I can't with the core game (which currently is in a zip file).

Comment: I don't see an issue with the updater needing administrator privileges

Comment: I'm thinking because the 'game' is business level it may be installed on a local business network with strong security, in which case the average user would not have administrator privileges? Keep in mind I am pretty green when it comes to developing & publishing windows apps like WPF.

Comment: I'm working in a filed simmilar to what you described and installing applications with admin privileges is a big nono for normal users. You need an IT guy for that at my place (if you can download the file that is. `exe` files are blocked by default). However I don't see a way of you getting around that unfortunately. Maybe make it a customizable installation path and let the users decide?

Comment: Yeah @TehMightyPotato, that's what I'm coming up against this issue. In our instance, due to security constraints, we're actually just going to send them a separate desktop machine, which doesn't need to dip into their VPN or anything, and can just use wifi. The only alternative is to let the user choose a download location on the PC which it'd allow, however some company internals won't allow ANY installs of exe's, like you said. So we're just gonna straight up give em a PC. So this issue is unsolved so far, but worked around. Thanks guys